# Correct method to get value of RadioGroup

Tags: android, android-studio

A complete java noob so my method of doing this might be wrong, but I am getting the value of a radiobutton in a radio group and comparing it to a value, which seems to be work for the most part but I'm having intermittent crashes:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.RadioButton.getText()' on a null object reference
```

which points to this line:

```
String selection = rb.getText().toString();
```

I have the following java code:

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroupAdd);
Integer checkedID = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedID);
String selection = rb.getText().toString();
if (selection.equals("Paint")) {
 //Do stuff here
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: what's wrong with [isChecked()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#isChecked())?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getCheckedRadioButtonId()`returns -1 if no radio button is selected. So your `findViewById()` will return `null`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#getCheckedRadioButtonId()

You could wrap the `getText()` and following code with a null pointer check, but as to "what is a better way to do this?" there isn't much detail in you question to answer that, and may be too broad anyway.

Comment: Thanks - I think this is the issue: getCheckedRadioButtonId()returns -1 if no radio button is selected. So your findViewById() will return null.